# dialog does not come up after uploading asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-dialog

my dialog does not popup after successfull upload? the upload works fine but   $("#dialog-confirm").dialog does not work?

```
<h2>
    upload Data</h2>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqueryform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jblock.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSubmit: function () {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").block({ message: '<h1><img src="/Content/busy.gif" /> uploading file...</h1>' });
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, result.message);

                //alert(result.message);

                //does not popup??
                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 140,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Ok":
                        function () {
                            alert('ok');
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    ,
                        Cancel: function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });


            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, 'Error uploading file');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<form id="ajaxUploadForm" action="<%= Url.Action("AjaxUpload", "Home")%>" method="post"    enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Upload a file</legend>
    <label>
        File to upload:
        <input type="file" name="file" />(100MB max size)</label>
    <input id="ajaxUploadButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
</form>


  public FileUploadJsonResult AjaxUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // TODO: Add your business logic here and/or save the file
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Simulate a long running upload

        // Return JSON
        return new FileUploadJsonResult { Data = new { message = string.Format("{0} uploaded successfully.", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)) } };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the [jquery.form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin for AJAXifying the form and returning JSON from your controller action. Here's what the [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) says about this scenario:

> Since it is not possible to upload
>   files using the browser's
>   XMLHttpRequest object, the Form Plugin
>   uses a hidden iframe element to help
>   with the task. This is a common
>   technique, but it has inherent
>   limitations. The iframe element is
>   used as the target of the form's
>   submit operation which means that the
>   server response is written to the
>   iframe. This is fine if the response
>   type is HTML or XML, but doesn't work
>   as well if the response type is script
>   or JSON, both of which often contain
>   characters that need to be repesented
>   using entity references when found in
>   HTML markup.
>
> To account for the challenges of
>   script and JSON responses, the Form
>   Plugin allows these responses to be
>   embedded in a textarea element and it
>   is recommended that you do so for
>   these response types when used in
>   conjuction with file uploads.

So for this to work the response from the server needs to look like this:

```
<textarea>{ message: 'file uploaded successfully' }</textarea>
```

Is it what this custom `FileUploadJsonResult` is doing in your controller action?

Comment: yes, this is my FileUploadJsonResult:  public class FileUploadJsonResult : JsonResult
    {
        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            this.ContentType = "text/html";
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<textarea>");
            base.ExecuteResult(context);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</textarea>");
        }
    }